# Xml file validation for different xml attributes

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

I have an upload button to upload XML files and display in grid. And I have a stored procedure that accepts `xml` which has given nodes (`<group></group>`).

If I upload a XML file to the stored procedure which has a node like `<anythingelse></anythingelse>`, it does not accept it.

How to write a condition for that so that I can raise an error?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE xml_data          
    @xml XML ,     
    @group varchar(50) = NULL,
AS         
    CREATE TABLE #XMLTble 
    (    
        [group] varchar(50),    
    )    
    
BEGIN     
    DECLARE @count numeric;    

    SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table_t1 

    SET NOCOUNT ON;          

    INSERT INTO #XMLTble ([group])         
        SELECT  
            Configuration.value('(Group/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(max)') AS [group]    
            FROM @xml.nodes('/Merchant/Configuration') AS TEMPTABLE(Configuration)    
  
    DELETE #XMLTble 
    FROM #XMLTble xc 
    INNER JOIN table_t1 gp ON xc.[group] = gp.[group];
   
    INSERT INTO table_t1    
        SELECT * 
        FROM #XMLTble     
    
    IF ((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table_t1 
    BEGIN      
        RAISERROR('Duplicated xml values',16,1);      
        RETURN      
    END      
END
```

The above condition is for duplicated values, and when I add xml of different format, it throws the same error, how do I write a condition for this?

Comment: Seems like you're trying to reinvent the XML validation wheel. Have you considered using SQL Server's built-in [XML schema collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-schema-collections-sql-server) and just validating the supplied XML against a well-defined schema?

Comment: The nodes names are in the script : Configuration.value('(Group/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(max)') AS [group]    
            FROM @xml.nodes('/Merchant/Configuration') AS TEMPTABLE(Configuration)  You can make the node names a variable (a string) but you would need to know the path before running the code.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning comment is the best answer. Please add your legit XML sample to the question.